# NuxtJS (Vue): How to get list of posts into Component or Layout?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am creating a static blog using nuxt-content. I'm trying to create a Navbar that list out the posts (*/content/posts/xxx.md*). This way I only need to create the new .md in the posts directory and the Navbar would be updated accordingly.

To do so I need a list of all posts that I can loop through, but currently I am struggling to get this list.

In [this](https://nuxtjs.org/blog/creating-blog-with-nuxt-content/) blog post by NuxtJS on creating a Static blog I can see they get exactly what I want with the code below, however it's on a Page (which can perform actions the Component / Layouts cannot). How can I replicate this on either Component (preferable) or Layout:

```
<script>
export default {
  async asyncData({ $content, params }) {
    const posts = await $content('posts', params.slug)
      .only(['title', 'description', 'slug', 'author'])
      .sortBy('createdAt', 'asc')
      .fetch()

    return {
      posts
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `vuex` store and save your posts in the store.
Then, you can get your posts from the store using `getters`

How to save your posts to the store?
You can use [NuxtServerInit](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/#the-nuxtserverinit-action) action for this. It has access to the `context` object and you can access your `$content` object from there and save your posts via `mutation`

Then in your navbar component you can get your `posts` using store `getters`